# How to get base path from path in shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, string, path

I would need to find a way in Bash (Linux shell in general) to get a **base path from a given path**. There are a few rules:

- in the given path there will be one directory called `ABC`.
- the directory `ABC` contains a subdirectory which I don't know the name of. Below I call it `XYZ`.

Given this path

```
/some/absolute/path/foo/ABC/XYZ/bar/path/here
```

the result should be:

```
/some/absolute/path/foo/ABC/XYZ
```

The problem I'm having is due to `XYZ`, because I don't know it, but need to keep it in the returned path.

Without the unknown `XYZ` I could do this:

```
pwd | sed -e 's/ABC.*/ABC/'
```

Does anyone have a solution how I can solve this in Bash? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r 's,^(.*/ABC/[^/]+).*,\1,'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in pure Bash:

```
p='/some/absolute/path/foo/ABC/XYZ/bar/path/here'
m=ABC
t=${p##*$m/}          # t=XYZ/bar/path/here
t=${t%%/*}            # t=XYZ
new=${p%$m/*}$m/$t    # new consists of "/some/absolute/path/foo/", "ABC", "/" and "XYZ"
```